# Rails feature test is not being run

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, capybara

I have a Rails feature test that is not being run. When I try `$ rspec spec/features` or `$ rspec` I get this output:

```
No examples found.

Finished in 0.00005 seconds
0 examples, 0 failures
```

Here is the code in my feature test that should be run:

```
# spec/features/alpha_sign_ups.rb
require 'spec_helper'

feature 'Alpha user sign ups' do
    scenario 'with a valid email' do
        visit root_path
        fill_in 'Email', with: "test@test.com"
        click_button 'Request Early Access'
        expect(page).to have_content('whatever')
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My file did not have a `_spec.rb` suffix. Rspec only runs files as tests if they have this suffix.

Comment: I knew this, yet just spent a good 20 minutes trying to figure out why my feature specs weren't running.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In the Relish documents, it says:

> by default, RSpec runs files that match "**/*_spec.rb"

so

```
spec/features/alpha_sign_ups_spec.rb
```

will do.

https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/configuration/pattern

Comment: yep, that's why I posted this question about why it's not running :P